# slideshow starting onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple script for a slideshow, which runs once and stops on last image:

```
function slideImages(){
  var $active = $('#portfolio_slider .active');
  var $next = ($('#portfolio_slider .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#portfolio_slider .active').next() : $('#portfolio_slider img:first');
  $next.css('z-index',2);
  $active.css('z-index',1);
  $next.animate({left:0},"slow",function(){

          $next.addClass('active');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // run every 1s
  setInterval('slideImages()', 1000);

  })
```

I want it to start on mouseover event (and not autorun), I think I should use setTimeout but I can't work it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an event that trigger the interval instead of the DOM ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // run every 1s
    $('#portfolio_slider').on('mouseover', function(){
        setInterval(slideImages, 1000);
        $(this).off('mouseover');
    })
})
```

Comment: this works! now the problem is that I want cycle to start on every mouseover, this woks only the first time; besides I have multiple slideshows on the same page, this works only on one of them and also makes each starting together on single mouseover on it, probably depending on same id; any idea?

Comment: @dario It work only on 1 of them because you are using an id, id = 1 element. Use class instead. For your others question, you need to rework all you code. You should use jQuery prototype. It is kinda advanced programming though. Let me show you an example : http://jsfiddle.net/c2y3ez7u/

Comment: I'll follow your suggestions; anyway, thinking of a single slideshow, how could it cycle on every mouseover and not only on first?

Comment: @dario When the last slide is shown, you should rerun this code `$('#portfolio_slider').on('mouseover', function(){
        setInterval(slideImages, 1000);
        $(this).off('mouseover');
    })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#portfolio_slider').on('mouseenter', slideImages);
});
```